# Is there any good IDE or WYSIWYG editor for graphviz?

Tags: macos, ide, editor, wysiwyg, graphviz

Actually I had downloaded an GUI for graphviz (dont remember the site), which said that they had won an Apple Design Award. But that tool really only displays an *.dot file I created. That's it. It's just called "Graphviz"... I guess that there are better tools around for using the Graphviz technology.

I tried this one: [link text](http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/)

Although they say that they won an Apple Design Award, I really can't see any special GUI there. Very poor interface.

Comment: As graphviz does automatic layout, what exactly do you expect from a  WYSIWYG editor? Visual property editing?

Comment: The plugin for the Atom editor is top-notch for working with GraphViz projects - https://atom.io/packages/graphviz-preview

Comment: There is also a Sublime Text 3 Plugin which can render graphviz image in real time. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Graphvizer

Answer (score 21):

The current version of Graphviz.app does not contain the "external editor" button shown in [rampion's screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814621/is-there-any-good-ide-or-wysiwyg-editor-for-graphviz/814639#814639) above - Or the Render/Stop buttons, and it has replaced the "settings" button with "attributes".  However, it can be used as described.

I downloaded 'graphviz-2.27.20101110.0545.pkg' from http://graphviz.org/Download_macos.php.  Note that there are several places to download various things which call themselves Graphviz:

- http://graphviz.org/Download_macos.php
- http://graphviz.org/Download..php
- http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/download/

Use the first one, I chose the most recent development snapshot - A glance at the mailing lists ([interest](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/) and [devel](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-devel/)) reveal that it's still pretty active, which you wouldn't know from the pixelglow sites that still have "Content coming soon" messages from 2004.

Anyways, when 2.27 is started, it throws up an "Open" dialog.  Opening a .dot file will show a graph, but cancelling reduces you to nothing but a menu bar.  Don't be dismayed, create a file with the text

```
graph graphname {
}
```

and call it something.dot.

Open that in Graphviz, and you get a GUI with an empty graph:

[image]

Type in some more text into the file, like this:

```
graph graphname {
  a -- b -- c -- d -- a;
  a -- c;
  b -- d;
}
```

The Graphviz window automatically updates when you save to show this:

[image]

There are a plethora of options in the "Attributes" toolbox, but it looks like they want you to edit the source by hand.  I kind of expected "Add vertex" and "Add edge" buttons, and the ability to move vertices around, but that's not what it's about, apparently.

So, apparently, the WYSIWYG editor is your favorite text editor on one side of the screen, and Graphviz on the other.  As far as an IDE goes, it looks like the best thing available right now is a printout of the [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php) for the DOT format. Not everybody's idea of a WYSIWYG editor or IDE, but it probably works for active users.

Comment: This should be selected as the "correct" answer since it explains how to do this with the *current* GraphViz version.

Comment: @jeffp - The author of the question hasn't been seen since November of '09, so that's unlikely to happen.  Plus, we're now on 2.28, with development proceeding on 2.29, so it's not truly *current* anymore.  (It is, however, more current than 1.13, which is the version cited in the highest-voted answer)

Answer (score 9):

[Graphviz.app](http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/) has a command to open the current dot file in an external editor.  If you use that, it will monitor the file handle for changes, and update the graph after each time you save in the external editor.  That's how you can get it to work as a WYSIWYG interface.

[image: graphviz]

The 'Edit' button's in the upper left hand corner, next to 'Settings'.

Actually it monitors the file handle continally anyway, so what I do is open the dot file in Graphviz.app, fire up vim and edit the dotfile (with `set backupcopy=yes`) and watch the graph update after each `:w`.

Comment: if you're talking about the Pixelglow software: I can't see any option to launch any editor. It simply opens an *.dot file and displays it. Nothing else. Which software do you mean?

Comment: I'm talking about Graphviz.app from pixelglow, yes.  See the above screenshot.

Comment: This is with version 1.13 (16).  I tried to install the new one just now (graphviz-2.22.2.pkg) but I couldn't get it to work on my machine, so it may have a different interface.

Comment: it seems you've got some lucky other version. mine really shows just a menu. that's it. No interface at all. If I open a file, then I only have a blank window with the rendered graph. But the instant refresh does work when I open it up in that app and then in an text editor.

Comment: 1.13 is still available : http://www.pixelglow.com/downloads/graphviz-1.13-v16.dmg

Comment: 1.13 is only available for ppc.  You can build your own copy of a newer version using homebrew, or just from source (but follow the homebrew recipe)

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly what you're asking for - but the potential of the projects I'm going to mention is pretty huge - as a graphviz fan I've been really amazed at what is now possible.

The short history:

- http://ushiroad.com/jsviz/ - ushiroad cooked up this lil guy. Using the Emscripten project he cross-compiled enough of graphviz to get layout and basic node stuff as a pure javascript app. You have to click the little round-arrow button on the bottom-right of the DOT src frame.

The only down-side (which in no way diminishes the awesomeness of porting graphviz to javascript) is the limitation on what you can do with it. it's basically just dot layout with a couple primary shaped nodes - doesn't support color. etc.

The author was awesome enough to upload his work to github, https://github.com/gyuque/livizjs

- https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js - looks like it took it to the next level, from the [demo page](http://mdaines.github.io/viz.js/) it looks as though vis.js can do everything the standard build of graphviz can do, but all in your browser.

So, if you were so inclined - you could pretty easily take one of the lightweight (but pro!) in-browser editors like [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) (it has vi key support) - and rig up a 'render' button like jsviz.

So.. not exactly what you were looking for. But holy moly for the person who spends a little time on this problem - a bounty of web based client-side graphing tools await.

Comment: I agree that vis.js looks promising, but unfortunately it doesn't have any commits on GitHub since the initial import 2 years ago.

Comment: Here is a working version: https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/

Answer (score 3):

The excellent [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) can import *.dot files, but sadly I don't think you can round-trip it back and export the edited results as a dot file natively.

Comment: OG uses graphviz, as far as i know... I think I'll get OG some day, when I make some coins on the app store ;)

Answer (score 3):

There was a UI called dotty. I don't remember it being very nice to use.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/dotty

Comment: Dotty is absolutely horrible. There are graphics glitches constantly, I can't even figure out how to save changes, and it's really hard to get the changes I want anyway.

Comment: Ease-of-use and glitches aside, my math professor said it's the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

[Pixelglow](http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/) looks like the site you're referring to.

I note they now offer an IPhone-enabled solution (!)

Comment: yes they do, but that's not an option. They should rather improve their mac app, I think ;) ... really, the app is not even close to what the screenshot shows. It consists only of a menu bar that allows to open a file and to zoom in and out. it hasn't got any more capacity then that. I don't believe they won any award.

Comment: Yes. I've not looked at it. I only note it for people's reference

Comment: Yes the original won an award which was largely for the adaption to Mac technology. It was branched and now left behind because it was a complete rewrite of the Graphviz rendering engine. Currently Glen is working on the new GUI for GraphViz viewing and rendering on Mac and Windows, which has stepped back a bit in GUI quality but is on the main track for the source. I believe AT&T are funding some of his work but not the excellent Instaviz on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be [tintfu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tintfu/). Unfortunately it does not let you edit the source-code directly.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use it... it doesn't display any graphical output, and it's easier to use a text editor than to edit the graph in the left pane.

Comment: I only gave it a quick try myself. When I tried it, it worked as advertised. But as you say, editing the source by hand is much easier, and so I did not follow up on this app.